# Booking System. checking for existing data

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check and compare the information on my input form with information that is stored in my database.
Basically. if trainer, sessionslot eventdate is the same dbtrainer, dbeventdate dbsessionslot ECHO "Booked";
                         Else insert into booking table

I know very little about programming, could really do with some help on this one.

This is snippet of the code i am using.

```
if(isset($_GET['add'])){
    $trainee = $_POST['txttrainer'];
    $trainer = $_POST['txttrainee'];
    $sessionSlot = $_POST['txtsession'];


    $eventdate = $month."/".$day."/".$year;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BOOKING WHERE trainer='$trainer' AND SessionSlot='$sessionslot");


    $sqlinsert = "insert into booking (Trainee,Trainer,sessionSlot,eventDate,dateAdded) values ('".$trainee."','".$trainer."','".$sessionSlot."','".$eventdate."',now())";
    $resultinsert = mysql_query($sqlinsert);

            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            if($numrows == 1) {
                echo "this timeslot is booked"
                if($resultinsert){
                    echo "Booking Successful....";
                 }else{
                     echo "Booking Failed";
                 }
             }
}
```

Comment: So what error are you recieving?

Answer (score 1):

```
    if(isset($_GET['add'])){
    $trainee = $_POST['txttrainer'];
    $trainer = $_POST['txttrainee'];
    $sessionSlot = $_POST['txtsession'];


    $eventdate = $month."/".$day."/".$year;
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM BOOKING WHERE trainer='$trainer' AND SessionSlot='$sessionslot");


    $sqlinsert = "insert into booking (Trainee,Trainer,sessionSlot,eventDate,dateAdded) values ('".$trainee."','".$trainer."','".$sessionSlot."','".$eventdate."',now())";


            $numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);
            if($numrows >0) {
                echo "this timeslot is booked"
             }else{
                 $resultinsert = mysql_query($sqlinsert);
                 if(mysql_error()==""){
                    echo 'time slot booked';
                 }else{
                    echo 'error';
                 }
             }
    }
```

Explanation:

if there are rows selected, the timeslot is booked, else execute the query. If there is no error with the query, then print out success.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `mysql_query`, the query is executed. So you're executing the `INSERT` before you check whether the `SELECT` returned a row or not.

That means you should place the `INSERT` part inside an `if($numrows != 1)` condition.

Please be aware that using `mysql_query` is deprecated: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php and you should use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL. Your code is vulnerable to SQL injections.